# Calculating "time ago" using OffsetDateTime in Java

Tags: java, duration, localdate, localdatetime, offsetdatetime

I currently have this code:

```java
public static String getTimeAgo(OffsetDateTime dateArg) {
    Instant instantNow = Instant.now();
    Instant instantThen = dateArg.toInstant();
    Duration comparedDuration = Duration.between(instantThen, instantNow);

    LocalDate localDate = dateArg.toLocalDate();
    LocalDate localDateToday = LocalDate.now(ZoneId.systemDefault());
    Period comparedPeriod = Period.between(localDate, localDateToday);

    ZonedDateTime zdt1 = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(instantThen, ZoneId.systemDefault());
    ZonedDateTime zdt2 = ZonedDateTime.ofInstant(instantNow, ZoneId.systemDefault());
    Calendar calendarFetched = GregorianCalendar.from(zdt1);
    Calendar calendarNow = GregorianCalendar.from(zdt2);

    Instant d1i = Instant.ofEpochMilli(calendarFetched.getTimeInMillis());
    Instant d2i = Instant.ofEpochMilli(calendarNow.getTimeInMillis());

    LocalDateTime startDateWeek = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(d1i, ZoneId.systemDefault());
    LocalDateTime endDateWeek = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(d2i, ZoneId.systemDefault());

    long weeksCalc = ChronoUnit.WEEKS.between(startDateWeek, endDateWeek);


    String s = "";
    if(comparedPeriod.getYears() > 0) {
        s += comparedPeriod.getYears() + " year" + ((comparedPeriod.getYears() == 1) ? " " : "s ");
    }

    if(weeksCalc > 4){
        s += comparedPeriod.getMonths() + " month" + ((comparedPeriod.getMonths() == 1) ? " " : "s ");

    }
    else{
        s += weeksCalc + " weeks ";

    }

    if (comparedPeriod.getDays() > 0){
        s += comparedPeriod.getDays() + " day" + ((comparedPeriod.getDays() == 1) ? " " : "s ");
    }

    if (comparedDuration.toHoursPart() > 0) {
        s += comparedDuration.toHoursPart() + " hour" + ((comparedDuration.toHoursPart() == 1) ? " " : "s ");
    }
    else{
        if(comparedDuration.toMinutesPart() > 0){
            s += comparedDuration.toMinutesPart() + " minute" + ((comparedDuration.toMinutesPart() == 1) ? " " : "s ");
        }

        else s += comparedDuration.toSecondsPart() + " seconds "; // lol lets just end it here...
    }

    return s + "ago";
}
```

The goal is to display "time ago" based off from given `OffsetDateTime` argument. This is to show the year, month, weeks, days, hours, minutes, all the way down to seconds, if said time units were not at `0`. But I am having trouble calculating the month as the result always come back as `0`, while having an "s" indicating that it is not truly `0`.

For example, running `System.out.println(Utils.getTimeAgo(OffsetDateTime.parse("2020-12-13T15:54:43.971273200-05:00")))` displays `1 year 0 months 1 hour ago` as its output...

Comment: You should drop `Calendar` immediately. You are already using the newer Java Date and Time API available in `java.time`.

Answer (score 2):

If you think on it, you’ll realize that rarely does it make sense to represent a span of time as a combination of years-months-days-hours-minutes-seconds.

That is why *java.time* splits out the scales into two separate classes:

- `Period` years-months-days
- `Duration` hours-minutes-seconds

### `org.threeten.extra.PeriodDuration`

If you insist on combing the two scales, I suggest adding the [*ThreeTen-Extra*](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) library to your project. This provides the [`PeriodDuration`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/PeriodDuration.html) class.

```
OffsetDateTime odtThen = … ;
OffsetDateTime odtNow = OffsetDateTime.now( odtThen.getOffset() ) ;
PeriodDuration pd = PeriodDuration.between( odtThen, odtNow ) ;
```

Interrogate to obtain each part. One way to do that is to loop on the list returned from [`PeriodDuration#getUnits`](https://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org.threeten.extra/org/threeten/extra/PeriodDuration.html#getUnits()).

---

As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70341493/calculating-time-ago-using-offsetdatetime-in-java/70341755#comment124343228_70341493), stop using `Calendar` class. Along with `Date` & `SimpleDateFormat`, these terrible date-time classes were entirely supplanted by the *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.